# Bash script to monitor multiple paths and end email notification when a new file is added

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, monitor

I have written a script to monitor 2 directories and to end an email notification if a new file gets added here, but it seems to be monitoring only the 1st directory and not the second (i don't get a notification when I add something to the 2nd directory), can anyone help me fix this?
script:

```
#!/bin/bash

monitor_dir=/path1/UnSent
monitor_dir1=/path2/failed

email=email1.com
email2=email2.com


files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "your file sent to UnSent" "$email" 

  files="$newfiles" 
done

files1=$(find "$monitor_dir1" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles1=$(find "$monitor_dir1" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files1") <(echo "$newfiles1"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "your file sent to failed" "$email2" 

  files1="$newfiles1" 
done
```

Comment: You should consider `inotifywait`

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ampersand `&` after the first loop `done &` might help. This will run the first loop in the background and continue with the second loop. Without the `&` the second loop will never be reached because of the first one running indefinitely.

The updated code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

monitor_dir=/path1/UnSent
monitor_dir1=/path2/failed

email=email1.com
email2=email2.com


files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "your file sent to UnSent" "$email" 

  files="$newfiles" 
done &

files1=$(find "$monitor_dir1" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles1=$(find "$monitor_dir1" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files1") <(echo "$newfiles1"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "your file sent to failed" "$email2" 

  files1="$newfiles1" 
done
```

Comment: @Bhavana, I am glad to help :) please also accept the answer if it solved your problem.